# ASP.NET Retrieve single value from a cookie with multiple keys

Tags: asp.net, cookies

I made a function in a class for all my Content Pages to use, to retrieve a single value from a cookie that has multiple keys. The problem is, the function is returning null every time, even though I can see the cookie in the browser.

This is the function in my class file.

```
public string getCookie(string name, string name2)
{
    string cookie = null;
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Cookies)
    {
        HttpCookie request = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[name];
        if(request != null)
        {
            if (request.HasKeys)
            {
                if (name2 != null)
                    cookie = request.Values[name2];
            }
            else
                cookie = request.Value;
        }
    }
    return cookie;
}
```

`name` is the name of the cookie

`name2` is the name of the key that has the value I'm trying to get

**EDIT:** I checked the process using breakpoints. Everything is going fine until
`cookie = request.Values[name2];` which is returning null.

**EDIT2:** I'm adding the cookie when a button is pressed on one page. After setting the cookie, that button redirects you to another page that checks on Page_Load if the cookie was added.

**EDIT3:** The process is like this:

Page1.aspx >> Press button >> Button adds cookie >> After adding cookie redirect to Page2.aspx

Page2.aspx >> Check if cookie exists on Page_Load >!> `getCookie` finds cookie but it's returning null in `request.Values[name2]`

**EDIT4:** Ok, I kinda solved it by looping through all the keys of the cookie and then comparing each key name with the parameter `name2`. Still, isn't there a way to obtain the value of a single key without looping?

```
public string getCookieRequest(string name, string name2)
{
    String cookie = null;
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Cookies)
    {
        HttpCookie request = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[name];
        if(request != null)
        {
            if (request.HasKeys)
            {
                if (name2!= null)
                {
                    //cookie = request.Values[name2];
                    int i = 0;
                    foreach (string key in request.Values.AllKeys)
                    {
                        if (request[key] == name2)
                            return request.Values.AllKeys[i];
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
                cookie = request.Value;
        }
    }
    return cookie;
}
```

Comment: debug that page with breakpoints and make sure cookie is not null

Comment: I did that already. As I said in my post, everything is going fine until `cookie = request.Values[name2];`. The cookie is not null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this worked for me. It works for obtaining a single value of a cookie with both single or multiple keys. Though I don't like looping through all the keys to find the value I'm looking for, I guess it's necessary:

```
public string getCookie(string name, string name2 = null)
{
    string cookie = null;
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Cookies)
    {
        HttpCookie request = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[name];
        if(request != null)
        {
            if (request.HasKeys)
            {
                if (name2!= null)
                {
                    foreach (string value in request.Values.AllKeys)
                        if (request[value] == name2)
                        {
                            cookie = value;
                            break;
                        }
                }
            }
            else
                cookie = request.Value;
        }
    }
    return cookie;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
HttpCookie ck = Request.Cookies["your cookie name"];
    if (ck != null )
    {
         string cookie = ck.Values["your key name"];
    }
```

ck will store cookie info and if it is not null than it will store key value in string. you can access any key value by changing your key name

Comment: Ehm...that's what I'm doing if you look at my code. Same results.

Comment: than your key name or cookie name is wrong or your cookie is null because it works perfectly for me

Comment: The name is well written, I have even copied the name ("_s") and the key name ("_s_tc") into the function parameters and it's still giving me null. Besides, it is actually detecting the cookie because it's returning true in `request.HasKeys`. But it's giving me null in `cookie = request.Values[name2]`.

Comment: are you getting name2 value here `if (name2 != null)`  ?

Comment: No? Why would I check if name2 is null if I'm supposed to send it as a parameter of the function.

Comment: because if cookie is created and key is correct than value must come there should be some issue with your key name. try to change key name of cookie

Comment: That's not the problem. The name is all good and the cookie is indeed created, else it wouldn't appear on my browser. Please check my fourth edit.